# To get the current time every second, use Calendar.getInstance(), but occur memory leak on java

Tags: android, memory, timer, calendar

my program is to check whether the current time is intime(go to work) or outtime(off work)

so, using timer, execute check method every seconds.

current I get current time I use `Calendar.getInstance()`

but `Calendar.getInstance()` is it seems that there is a lot of memory leak than I thought.

[image]

my source.

```
@Override
public void updateStatus() { //this method execute every seconds
   RunState newState = doTimeComparison(Calendar.getInstance()); //RunState 'IN' or 'OUT' 
   displayInOut(newState);
}
```

this source if current time is before 12 pm. newState is 'IN'  after 12 pm. newState is 'OUT'

I want how to get the current time, excluding `Calendar.getInstance()`.?
or if I use `Calendar.getInstance()`, is there a way to reduce memory leak?

if you solve this problem. please comment. thanks.

Comment: `System.currentTimeMillis()`. Can't you set an alarm for this, instead of constantly checking yourself?

Answer (score 0):

what i understand is that you are using `Calendar.getInstance()` to get the current time, you should use `calendar.getTime()` instead

also when you call `Calendar.getInstance()` you are doing it wrong, since you are calling a class constructor, you have to create an object instead and call an object method like getTime().

```
Calendar calendar =Calendar.getInstance()
calendar.getTime()
```

Comment: This does not make any difference `Calendar.getInstance()` is preset with  `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

Comment: @ADM finally `Calendar.getInstance` and `System.currentTimeMillis()` same work ?

Comment: Yeah that's what I said .

Comment: oh.. so then I put `Calendar.getInstance()` in the constructor, is there a way to call `calendar.getTime()` every seconds?

Comment: Why dont just use System.currentTimeInMillies() first thing .?? In conjunction with a Timer .if this shoots your requirement .

Answer (score 0):

I found because the Canlendar.getInstance is not a singleton method, your updateState is a method which often was called, so your app occurs the memory leak.

```
public static Calendar getInstance()
{
    return createCalendar(TimeZone.getDefault(), Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.FORMAT));
}
private static Calendar createCalendar(TimeZone zone,
                                       Locale aLocale)
{
    // BEGIN Android-changed: only support GregorianCalendar here
    return new GregorianCalendar(zone, aLocale);
    // END Android-changed: only support GregorianCalendar here
}
public GregorianCalendar(TimeZone zone, Locale aLocale) {
    super(zone, aLocale);
    gdate = (BaseCalendar.Date) gcal.newCalendarDate(zone);
     setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
 }
```

so I suggest you can  directly call System.currentTimeMills but you should solve the timezone. you can also

```
Canlendar canlendar = CanlenDar.getInstance();
@Override
public void updateStatus() { //this method execute every seconds
   RunState newState = doTimeComparison(canlendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)); //RunState 'IN' or 'OUT' 
  displayInOut(newState);
```

}